# Rooted device: "This device, OS, or software is not compatible with Pokémon GO"

Tags: cyanogenmod, pokemon-go, root-cloak

Just when I was about to reach level 23, Pokemon Go stopped working with this message:

> This device, OS, or software is not compatible with Pokémon GO

I am using CyanogenMod 13.0-20160817-NIGHTLY-hammerhead (Android 6.0.1) on a Nexus 5, and can't live without root.

QUESTION: Is there a way to make it work again?

[image: This device, OS, or software is not compatible with Pokémon GO]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Since the 0.37 update on android, Root users have been forced out of the game. Niantic claim this to cut down on hacking (but a better option would be to not open if allow.mock.location is 1)

[Source 1](http://www.gamenguide.com/articles/45186/20160912/pokemon-go-latest-news-updates-niantic-bans-rooted-jailbroken-devices-players-complain-says-not-all-owners-of-rooted-devices-cheat.htm) - A report that talks about the new updates limits.

Either way, you do still have an option: Using Magisk, You can play Pokemon Go again with root. It is the exact same method as Allowing Android Pay with root, but I'll [Link it here, for simplicity](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/09/11/guide-play-pokemon-go-0-37-rooted-android-magisk/)

Answer (score 1):

There are methods called root cloaking. This is the process of hiding root from specific apps. I'd recommend checking out these posts for more information:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-rootcloak-completely-hide-root-t2574647

http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.devadvance.rootcloak2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 1) Download the superuser app
2) go to devlopper option and enable root for apps
3) go to superuser and go to settings and click clean root from phone and then niantic cant see it on your phone anymore

Comment: Thanks! Does it still allow me to use root in other applications though?

Comment: No. It removes it flat.

Comment: As my question says, I "can't live without root". I guess this solution would mean disabling and enabling root everytime I want to use the app.

Comment: Important! For anyone that had previously rooted their phone and can't access pokemon go even after unrooting: You need to FLASH BOOT.IMG from your rom.
That is only what helped me because that way you are deleting every trace of root, and pokemon go is looking for everything root related to defend from hackers.