# Bluestacks can emulate Android and play Angry Bird but not Pokemon Go?

Tags: bluestacks, pokemon-go

It is a bit strange Bluestacks (4.270) can run on the Mac, and run Angry Birds, Cut the Rope, but when Pokemon Go is run, the spinner just spins and cannot log in.  Is there anything special about this app and is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Possibly because Pokemon Go prevents itself to run on Android emulators (similar to [rooted devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/157731/44325)) to prevent cheating.

Comment: so emulators cannot make itself just look like an Android phone (that we buy for US$99)?

Comment: @StefanieGauss They could but it is a lot work and if you do so and publish it everybody who don't want to let an app run on an emulator can get the emulator and find how which property you forgot of in which other way this emulator can be identified. I would assume that there are a lot of emulator that can't be detected but they are kept private (e.g. anti virus companies most likely have such an emulator).